# mount nfs with nolock option, do not take effect

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I want to mount a nfs volume with nolock option, and it does mount success.
But, the result seem that,  the nolock option doesn't work.

```
[root@k8s-worker-2 opt]# umount nfs-test1/
[root@k8s-worker-2 opt]# mount -t nfs -o nolock,local_lock=all 369d24acc5-iba25.cn-shanghai.nas.aliyuncs.com:/ /opt/nfs-test1/
[root@k8s-worker-2 opt]# mount | grep nfs-test1
369d24acc5-iba25.cn-shanghai.nas.aliyuncs.com:/ on /opt/nfs-test1 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.83.54,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.83.57)
```

even the local_lock option doesn't seems ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `mount` begins from upper NFS protocol version and descends to lower. In your case NFS server supports version 4 therefore version 4 will be used. But NFS4 doesn't support `lock/nolock` and `local_lock` options. 
[man 5 nfs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs). If you want to use this lock options, then you need append `vers=3` option to your mount command.

Comment: I've just forgotten to add that NFS 4 has builtin locking mechanism instead of RPC lock mechanism in NFS2/3.