# Permissions problems configuring a NFS server and client between Ubuntu 18.04 x64 and Ubuntu 18.04 Arm64

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, nfs, arm, shared-folders

Because I have a little space on the sd card of my jetson nano,I have installed the nfs server on Ubuntu 18.04 x64 bit and the nfs common client on ubuntu 18.04 for arm64 on the jetson nano. I have followed this tutorial :

https://www.tecmint.com/install-nfs-server-on-ubuntu/

I have issued the following commands :

on the server side :

```
sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9

chmod -R 777 /home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9
```

on the client / jetson nano side :

```
sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9

chmod -R 777 /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9
```

and then I have created a script like this :

```
xhost +

sudo mount 192.168.1.6:/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9  /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9

sudo mount -t sysfs /sys/ /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/sys/

sudo mount -t proc /proc/ /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/proc/

sudo mount --bind /dev /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/dev/

sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/dev/pts/

sudo mount --bind /dev/shm /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/dev/shm/
```

I've logged inside the chroot with this command :

```
sudo chroot /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/ /bin/su -l root

Ok.
```

I tried to update and upgrade the packages of the i386 chroot and this is what happened :

```
apt update

.......

Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed

- SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)

W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed -

SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)

W: Not using locking for nfs mounted lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. -

pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease failed - Operation not permitted)


root@ziomario-desktop:~# apt upgrade


Reading package lists... DoneBuilding dependency tree      

Reading state information... Done

Calculating upgrade... Done

The following packages will be upgraded:  teamviewer1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 15.6 MB of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

W: Not using locking for nfs mounted lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontendW: Not using locking for nfs mounted lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lockW:

chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed

- SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)

W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed

- SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)

W: Not using locking for nfs mounted lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

something is wrong with the permissions ?. I'm not able to understand what's wrong.

This is how I have configured the NFS on the server side :

```
sudo nano /etc/exports

/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9  192.168.1.3(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

**where :**

> `192.168.1.3` : is the ip of the nano
>
> `/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9` : the folder that I want to make available only to the ip number of the nano

on the client / nano side I did :

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.6:/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9  /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9
```

**where :**

> `192.168.1.6` : is the IP of the server,ubuntu 18.04 64 bit
> `/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9` : is the folder of
> the server that I want to make >available to client-nano
> `/root/Scrivania/work/qemu-chroot-I9` : is the folder where I want to
> mount the folder of the > server

this is the mixed full (network) path where It is saved the chroot i386,that I want to access through the nano :

```
/root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386/
```

I hope that everything is clear and that someone can give me some good suggestion to fix the permission problems that I have. thanks.

Comment: On the client, as the root user, what does the following command return:  touch /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/test123

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld

Comment: root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9# pathlld ./chroot-bionic-i386-no
drwxrwxrwx 5 nobody nogroup 4096 feb  2 01:34 .
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
drwxrwxrwx 20 nobody nogroup 4096 feb  1 04:02 ./chroot-bionic-i386-no

Comment: touch /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9/chroot-bionic-i386-no
= no output

Comment: When you ran the "touch" command, was the file created, and if so, what were it's owner and group?

Comment: I fixed it,changing this :

sudo mount 192.168.1.6:/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9  /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9

with this :

sudo mount -t nfs -o nolock,local_lock=all 192.168.1.6:/home/loziomario/Scrivania/Nano/qemu-chroot-I9  /root/Scrivania/Work/qemu-chroot-I9

and the version of nfs that I'm using on the server is the 3.

I've got the solution here :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430570/mount-nfs-with-nolock-option-do-not-take-effect